# How to compare data attributes of parent and child?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to compare the data attributes of a child div to its parent div and if they do not match then hide the child element.  I want to be able to compare for each instance of the parent child relationship.  .test is the parent and .event is the child.  Here is what I have.

```
    if ($(".event").data("campaign-id") != $(".event").parent().data("campaign-id")) {
        $(".event").hide();
    }
```

Comment: why don't you try a simple solution `function checkAndHide($elem) {
   if ($elem.data("campaign-id") != $elem.parent().data("campaign-id")) {
        $elem.hide();
   }
  
}  

checkAndHide($(".event"));`

Answer (score 3):

`data` as getter returns specified datum of the first selected element in the set. Your script hides the all `.event` elements when the first `.event` element's `campaign-id` datum matches with it's parent `campaign-id` datum. You could use the `.filter()` method:

```
$(".event").filter(function() {
   return $(this).data("campaign-id") !== $(this.parentNode).data("campaign-id");
}).hide();
```

If you are getting `data-campaign-id` attributes and not the data stored by jQuery, another option is:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.event'), function(el) {
    var c = el.getAttribute('data-campaign-id'),
        p = el.parentNode.getAttribute('data-campaign-id');
    if ( c !== p ) {
        el.style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.each()` for this task:

```
 $(".event").each(function(){
     if($(this).data("campaign-id") != $(this).parent().data("campaign-id"))    
     {
          $(this).hide();
     }
 });
```